# How to have KafkaProducer to use a mock Schema Registry for testing?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm using `KafkaProducer` in my test cases and my producer uses the `schemaRegistryUrl` which points a my local instance of `Schema Registry`. Is there a way to mock how `KafkaProducer` connects with the Schema Registry? That is, to have `KafkaProducer/Consumer` in my tests to work without a running instance of Schema Registry.

Comment: Probably helpful if you are more clear what you are testing here. Can you clarify if you need the schema registry function? If you do, then you can't mock test its function really. If you don't need to test its function then what are you testing?

Answer (score 16):

https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.java

In 5.3.x, you can find a MOCK_URL_PREFIX = "mock://", so just set the test schemaRegistryUrl with the prefix "mock://", like: "mock://testurl".

Comment: The github url has moved. Can you update that.
Btw, just adding mock://testurl for my schemaRegistryUrl property worked like a charm!

Comment: I second @VivekSethi request. Is there any documentation saying to use this? I couldn't find anything anywhere. I came across this solution purely by chance. It works like a charm

Comment: Work great also for me. It's can be great if you can add any link that can explain what exactly happen when it was request mock:// url or add your explanation.. Is it possible to make additional use of it for tests or is it unique for a mocking schema?

Comment: New links: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/764e345f1f943065801d5034f285c3ad4156eaaf/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/testutil/MockSchemaRegistry.java#L47 and https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/9c2327084763e85f3617cef5260bd5f9add22474/schema-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java#L72

Answer (score 14):

There absolutely is. The KafkaAvroSerializer and KafkaAvroDeserializer both have a constructor that takes in a SchemaRegistryClient. You can use a MockSchemaRegistryClient as the SchemaRegistryClient. Here's a code snippet showing how to do that:

```java
private MockSchemaRegistryClient mockSchemaRegistryClient = new MockSchemaRegistryClient();
private String registryUrl = "unused";

public <T> Serde<T> getAvroSerde(boolean isKey) {
    return Serdes.serdeFrom(getSerializer(isKey), getDeserializer(isKey));
}

private <T> Serializer<T> getSerializer(boolean isKey) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, true);
    map.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, registryUrl);
    Serializer<T> serializer = (Serializer) new KafkaAvroSerializer(mockSchemaRegistryClient);
    serializer.configure(map, isKey);
    return serializer;
}

private <T> Deserializer<T> getDeserializer(boolean key) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true");
    map.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, registryUrl);
    Deserializer<T> deserializer = (Deserializer) new KafkaAvroDeserializer(mockSchemaRegistryClient);
    deserializer.configure(map, key);
    return deserializer;
}
```

Comment: And what if the code is not instantiating Serializers, but simply specifying the class in Kafka.properties? E.g. value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating your own Custom KafkaAvroSerializer.

In your appication.yml for test instead of io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer use the custom class as below

```
producer: 
  value-serializer: com.project.application.custom.MycustomKafkaAvroSerializer
```

```
package com.project.application.custom;
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer;
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.MockSchemaRegistryClient;

import java.util.Map;

public class MycustomKafkaAvroSerializer extends KafkaAvroSerializer {
    public MycustomKafkaAvroSerializer() {
        super();
        super.schemaRegistry = new MockSchemaRegistryClient();
    }

    public MycustomKafkaAvroSerializer(SchemaRegistryClient client) {
        super(new MockSchemaRegistryClient());
    }

    public MycustomKafkaAvroSerializer(SchemaRegistryClient client, Map<String, ?> props) {
        super(new MockSchemaRegistryClient(), props);
    }
}
```

Also add value to schema registry url although it won't be used but it shouldn't be left blank.

```
properties:
  schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the producer property `schema.registry.url` to a mock URL:

```
schema.registry.url: "mock://my-scope"
```

The value after the two slashes is the scope.
In your integration test you can retrieve the `SchemaRegistryClient` for the defined scope and register for example a JSON schema:

```java
SchemaRegistryClient client = MockSchemaRegistry.getClientForScope("my-scope");
client.register("my-subject", new JsonSchema("{...}"));
```